# SN74LS32N Not Working Correctly

Tags: digital-logic, integrated-circuit

I am using a SN74LS32N as an OR gate in a project, and I have hooked it up to an Arduino, but even when none of the inputs are powered, the LED that I hooked up to the output turns on. Why is this chip not working correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

74LS32 is a LSTTL series chip (really DTL). If you leave the inputs unconnected they are effectively at "1". You need to ground each input to get a "0".

Each input has a 20K typical [pullup resistor](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn74ls32.pdf).

[image]

Comment: If my inputs are grounded, how am I able to set them to 1?

Comment: You need to actively pull them to ~0V with the Arduino outputs, not leave them open.

Comment: Thanks. I was able to get this working with the OR gates, and an AND gate.